# Called method current selected fragment viewpager from parent activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Huy guys, I have problem with my App. I created viewpager with some fragment.
this my viewpager ini my parent activity

```
   private int current_posisition_page ;

         @Override
            protected v

oid onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    .....
          viewpager.setAdapter(new PagePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
            viewpager.setCurrentItem(999);


            viewpager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

                // This method will be invoked when a new page becomes selected.
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                     current_posisition_page = position;
                }

                // This method will be invoked when the current page is scrolled
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                }


                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                }
            });

    .......

    }

     private class PagePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

            public PagePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
                return PageFragment.newInstance(pos);

            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 1000;
            }

        }
    }
```

and this my fragment

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {

public static PageFragment newInstance(int page_index) {
        PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(Variabel.page_index, String.valueOf(page_index));
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            page_index = getArguments().getString(Variabel.page_index);
        }

        activity=(MainActivity)getActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_page, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, v);

        return v;
    }

  public void setSelectedAyat(String aya_id, String sura_name) {
        surat.setText("Surat " + sura_name);
        ayat.setText("Ayat " + aya_id);
}

}
```

Now I called method current selected fragment viewpager from parent activity:

```
PageFragment page = (PageFragment) adapter.getItem(current_posisition_page);
        page.setSelectedAyat(aya_id, sura_name);
```

but I get Error :

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to
>   com.ad.alquran.kemendag.fragment.PageFragment

in line : `PageFragment page = (PageFragment) adapter.getItem(current_posisition_page);`

so how to fix it ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably this line causing issue:

```
viewpager.setAdapter(new PagePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
```

Because `adapter` object for calling `getItem` method but in `ViewPager` `setAdapter` method passing different object of `PagePagerAdapter` class:

```
adapter=new PagePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and also make sure calling `getItem` method after setting adapter for ViewPager.

**EDIT:**

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference

Because not initializing `surat` and `ayat`. do it as:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_page, container, false);
        //... 
         surat=(TextView)v. findViewById(R.id.<surat_id_in_xml>);
         ayat=(TextView)v. findViewById(R.id.<ayat_id_in_xml>);
        return v;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks sir, but now i get error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference` in line `activity.surat.setText("Surat " + sura_name);` , surat is declared in fragment

Comment: It's have initialize in my fragment, but still null object reference :(

Comment: @AmayDiam: then probably calling before Fragment is added in ViewPager